# I want to display icons or image instead of Only Text in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

I am using [this Library](https://pub.dev/packages/graphite). I am passing a String containing Dictionary to this and it gives the graphs accordingly. I want to show an image or Icon instead of the text provided in String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change in the library files "GraphiteCell",I found out this class from the library. You can edit the library as you want. Where they have set text only. Text(node.id)
You can put icon here but now you have to pass icons from your class and change every classes respectively.

Comment: Error: Getter not found: 'Icons'.
      Icons.mail_outline,
      ^^^^^

I am getting this error now.

Comment: May be this library does not support icons. try to add Image.asset();